# Custom prefix for Connect Direct pnum

Tags: linux, configuration, connect-direct

Is there a way to specify a custom numerical prefix to the pnum that gets generated by the CD process? For example, if I set a custom prefix of 123 then the first process's pnum would be 1231. This is for CD 6.1 running on RHEL7.

I couldn't find any information about how to manipulate the generated pnum in the IBM documentation.